# mongoimport - an empty object { } field value imports as null value

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I want to manually add some data into a new mongodb. For this I write the json files and run `mongoimport` for importing.
This is an example of an original file:

```
{
    "val": {}
}
```

Yet, in the new database, the value `{}` is turned into `null`:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6023b9a532d713e97f5dc70c"),
  "val": null
}
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Is there a way to prevent this?

Due to some restrictions I have to use the `--legacy` flag on `mongoimport`.

My versions are:

```
$ mongoimport --version
mongoimport version: 100.2.0
$ mongod --version
db version v4.4.1
```

Comment: WIth v4.2.8 it works fine (i.e., as expected imported `{ "_id" : ObjectId("6023bf3f80d9cb39be0ca8d0"), "val" : {  } }`). Are you using any options, etc.

Comment: I will edit my question to include this. I have to use the `--legacy` flag. Sorry I didn't mention this in the beginning :)

Comment: With the `--legacy` option, I see the same output as you do - `null`.